# Istio RouteRules v1alpha3. Where to store the certificates. k8s Secrets?

Tags: istio

Isn't it possible to use k8s secret objects to store certificates?

In the doc (https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/):

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-tls-ingress
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-tls-ingress-gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    hosts:
    - "*"
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /etc/certs/server.pem
      privateKey: /etc/certs/privatekey.pem
```

The serverCertificate doc says:

> REQUIRED if mode is SIMPLE or MUTUAL. The path to the file holding the
>   server-side TLS certificate to use.

So it seems it is not possible to use k8s secrets to store the certificates but a fix path (in the worker node?) is needed. Is this right?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not right.

That path is the internal path of istio proxies.

For example with the Istio chart installation it is created a default istio proxy. If you list the deployments there is one called istio-ingressgateway.

If you edit/describe it you get:

```
  template:
    metadata:
      ....
      labels:
        istio: ingressgateway
....

volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/certs
          name: istio-certs
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs
          name: ingressgateway-certs
          readOnly: true

....

volumes:
      - name: istio-certs
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          optional: true
          secretName: istio.default
      - name: ingressgateway-certs
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          optional: true
          secretName: istio-ingressgateway-certs
```

Now in the Gateway Istio objects you bind your Gateway to a "Proxy":

```
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
```

Is inside that proxy where the certificates are, and those certificates come from secret objects. As you can see in the example I pasted the "volumes" section uses "Secret" k8s objects.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/#add-a-secure-port-https-to-our-gateway

> Create the secret istio-ingressgateway-certs in namespace istio-system using kubectl. The Istio gateway will automatically load the secret
>
> The secret MUST be called istio-ingressgateway-certs in the istio-system namespace, or it will not be mounted and available to the Istio gateway.
>
> The location of the certificate and the private key MUST be /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs, or the gateway will fail to load them.

EDIT: https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/secure-ingress/#configure-a-tls-ingress-gateway contains the phrases mentioned in the block quotes.  The documentation has likely been updated & made the above link less relevant.